# Problem with Git, Windows 10 and *.js Files in node project

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, git

There is a file in the project folder name (*.js). When I clone that repository, firstly I wasn't getting any files, and now when I was somehow able to get the working tree locally, whole project is being detected as unstaged changes. So to remove this, I ran

> git reset --hard

but the error comes, saying:

> error: unable to create file src/scripts/*.js: Invalid argument
> fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'.

I think this is a problem with the filename or git in windows. I am not exactly sure.

I just want the whole repository be treated normally as other repositories. A normal clone and I can start working.

Comment: If this file name realy contains `*` then you cannot create such file in Windows

Comment: Yeah, it does. The thing is, the person who created the repo, works on Mac and I guess, wildcard characters like '*' are allowed in MacOS. So when I try to clone it on windows, error is occurred. So, there's no work around for this kind of situation?

Comment: You can try to rename a file in a remote repository if you have any web access to it (like GitHub).

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it. So this is the only way out then I guess.